# How to free up resources in the new MVVMLight V4

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, resource-cleanup

I would like to know which is the best way to clean up resources in the newly fashioned ViewModelLocator for MVVM-Light V4. As far as I know, until version 3, the method *ViewModelLocator.Cleanup()* invoked the rest of the viewmodels' *Cleanup()* methods.

In version 4, with the new ViewModel Templates the Cleanup() methods are not included, nor they are generated when added to the *ViewModelLocator*. As I read in other similar questions related to V3, V4 was planned to centralize cleaning resources, so how can it be achieved?

Thank you.

Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are gone from the templates but are still a good standard practice (they may come back yet as V4 is still a beta)

Basically just implement the clean up method your self and ensure that it is called at the appropriate time on existing / clean-up of the app.

The clean-up function isn't called by the MVVM framework itself as it is, you have to call it manually. (shoot me if I'm wrong in that statement there :D)